# Ruby - cURL throws undefined method `post' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, curl, post

I am getting `undefined method 'posts' for nil:NilClass` error in my website logs when trying to run a ruby script file which sends a POST request to my Ruby on Rails website. 
it also errors right underneath:

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

ruby script:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://myapp.com/posts")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.set_form_data(
"title" => "blatest",
)

req_options = {
use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do   |http|
http.request(request)
end
```

my posts_controller.rb create method :

```
def create
  @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params) <<< line 25
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'New post' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, post: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I am using a form and multipart form but testing only 1 param first 'title' which works when I create the post through the website form. But the curl request doesn't do anything.Please help... :(

Comment: It's because `current_user` is nil. You're not passing in any information to the server to indicate who the user is. You will probably need to send some kind of authentication token in your request so that devise can sign the user in.

Comment: Any idea how that can be done please? Any examples elsewhere etc??

Answer (score 0):

The `posts` method is being called on `current_user` but there is no current user or session because the post request is coming from your script.

You're going to have to create an authentication strategy that is usable by your script.

Alternatively, if you are okay with having this controller action respond successfully to anonymous requests you'll have to pass in the user another way, like adding a param.

```
Something like this:

def create
  user = current_user || User.find(params[:post][:user_id])
  @post = user.posts.build(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: 'New post' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, post: @post }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

And then add the 'user_id' to you script

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse("https://myapp.com/posts")
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.set_form_data(
"title" => "blatest",
"user_id" => '1'
)

req_options = {
use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
}

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do   |http|
http.request(request)
end
```

I wouldn't leave this in a live web app because you are then creating an controller action that allows a script to create a post as any user with no security. An easy target for abuse. However this should get your test of concept working. Just be sure to beef up security afterwards.